# filecopy function is slower than cp command

Tags: swift, cocoa, cp

When copying a 7 GB file, the `filecopy` function is always about 20% slower than the `cp` command. I tested using my MacBook Pro 14" M1 and an external SSD connected via USB.

- Mac to Mac

  - filecopy: 4.78s
  - cp: 3.40s
- Mac to SSD

  - filecopy: 20.22s
  - cp: 15.93s
- SSD to Mac

  - filecopy: 20.61s
  - cp: 16.64s

I use the following code:

```
let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
openPanel.runModal()
let source = openPanel.urls[0]
openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
openPanel.runModal()
let destination = openPanel.urls[0].appendingPathComponent(source.lastPathComponent)

source.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { sourcePath in
    destination.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { destinationPath in
        let state = copyfile_state_alloc()
        defer {
            copyfile_state_free(state)
        }
        let date = Date()
        if copyfile(sourcePath, destinationPath, state, copyfile_flags_t(COPYFILE_ALL | COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW | COPYFILE_EXCL)) != 0 {
            print(NSError(domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: Int(errno)))
        }
        print(-date.timeIntervalSinceNow)
    }
}
```

and the very basic `cp` command:

```
time cp /path/to/source /path/to/destination
```

Is there a faster way to copy files? Am I doing something wrong with `filecopy`?

Comment: I found the command line and copyfile to be fairly equal in speed. But it could be because I have a different machine. However, FileManager was significantly faster than both.