# Making filecopy faster by changing block size

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit, foundation

I'm using the `filecopy` function to copy many files and I noticed that it always takes longer than similar tools like `cp` or a Finder copy (I already did a comparison in my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297525/filecopy-function-is-slower-than-cp-command)). What I didn't know before was that I can set the block size which apparently can have a big influence on how fast the file copy operation is.

The question now is: what should I consider before manually setting the block size? Does it make sense to have a block size that is not a power of 2? Can certain block sizes cause an error, such as a value that is too large (for the Mac the code is running on, or for the source and target devices)? When should or shouldn't I deviate from the default? Is there a way to find out the optimal block size for given source and target devices, or at least one that performs better than the default?

In the following sample code I tried to measure the average time for varying block sizes, but I'm not sure it's the best way to measure it, since each loop iteration can have wildly different durations.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        openPanel.runModal()
        let source = openPanel.urls[0]
        openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        openPanel.runModal()
        let destination = openPanel.urls[0].appendingPathComponent(source.lastPathComponent)
        let date = Date()
        let count = 10
        for _ in 0..<count {
            try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: destination)
            do {
                try copy(source: source, destination: destination)
            } catch {
                preconditionFailure(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        print(-date.timeIntervalSinceNow / Double(count))
    }
    
    func copy(source: URL, destination: URL) throws {
        try source.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { sourcePath in
            try destination.withUnsafeFileSystemRepresentation { destinationPath in
                let state = copyfile_state_alloc()
                defer {
                    copyfile_state_free(state)
                }
//                var bsize = Int32(16_777_216)
                var bsize = Int32(1_048_576)
                if copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_BSIZE), &bsize) != 0 || copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CB), unsafeBitCast(copyfileCallback, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)) != 0 || copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_STATUS_CTX), unsafeBitCast(self, to: UnsafeRawPointer.self)) != 0 || copyfile(sourcePath, destinationPath, state, copyfile_flags_t(COPYFILE_ALL | COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW | COPYFILE_EXCL)) != 0 {
                    throw NSError(domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: Int(errno))
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private let copyfileCallback: copyfile_callback_t = { what, stage, state, src, dst, ctx in
        if what == COPYFILE_COPY_DATA {
            if stage == COPYFILE_ERR {
                return COPYFILE_QUIT
            }
            var size: off_t = 0
            copyfile_state_get(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_COPIED), &size)
            let appDelegate = unsafeBitCast(ctx, to: AppDelegate.self)
            if !appDelegate.setCopyFileProgress(Int64(size)) {
                return COPYFILE_QUIT
            }
        }
        return COPYFILE_CONTINUE
    }
    
    private func setCopyFileProgress(_ progress: Int64) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Off topic but I'm curious, how does the speed of `FileManager.copyItem(at:to:)` compare to `filecopy`?

Comment: Didn't check, as I'm only interested in copying a file with progress reporting.