# Why is fcopyfile faster than copyfile?

Tags: macos, foundation, file-copying

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76297525/filecopy-function-is-slower-than-cp-command) I asked why `copyfile` is slower than the `cp` Terminal command. In [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77703218/making-filecopy-faster-by-changing-block-size) I asked how I can make `copyfile` faster by changing the block size.

Now I discovered that the `cp` implementation on macOS is [open source](https://github.com/apple-open-source/macos/blob/master/file_cmds/cp/cp.c) and that when copying regular files it doesn't use `copyfile` but `fcopyfile`. In a test I noticed that `fcopyfile` by default seems to be faster than `copyfile`.

When copying a 7 GB file I get about the same results I observed when comparing `filecopy` to `cp`:

- `copyfile`: 4.70 s
- `fcopyfile`: 3.44 s

When setting a block size of `16_777_216`, `copyfile` becomes faster than `fcopyfile`:

- `copyfile`: 3.20 s
- `fcopyfile`: 3.53 s

Is this expected and why is it so? I would have expected that they both have the same performance, and when changing the block size they would still have the same performance.

Here is the test code. Change `#if true` to `#if false` to switch from `fcopyfile` to `copyfile`:

```
import Foundation
import System

let source = "/path/to/source"
let destination = "/path/to/destination"

#if true

let state = copyfile_state_alloc()
defer {
    copyfile_state_free(state)
}
//var bsize = 16_777_216
//copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_BSIZE), &bsize)
let sourceFd = try! FileDescriptor.open(source, .readOnly)
let destinationFd = try! FileDescriptor.open(destination, .writeOnly)
if fcopyfile(sourceFd.rawValue, destinationFd.rawValue, state, copyfile_flags_t(COPYFILE_ALL | COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW | COPYFILE_EXCL | COPYFILE_UNLINK)) != 0 {
    print(NSError(domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: Int(errno)))
}
try! sourceFd.close()
try! destinationFd.close()

#else

source.withCString { sourcePath in
    destination.withCString { destinationPath in
        let state = copyfile_state_alloc()
        defer {
            copyfile_state_free(state)
        }
//        var bsize = 16_777_216
//        copyfile_state_set(state, UInt32(COPYFILE_STATE_BSIZE), &bsize)
        if copyfile(sourcePath, destinationPath, state, copyfile_flags_t(COPYFILE_ALL | COPYFILE_NOFOLLOW | COPYFILE_EXCL | COPYFILE_UNLINK)) != 0 {
            print(NSError(domain: NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code: Int(errno)))
        }
    }
}

#endif
```

Comment: You wrote "it doesn't use copyfile but fcopyfile" but when I look at the source you linked to I can't find a single instance of `fcopyfile`; only `copyfile`.

Comment: `if fcopyfile(...)` is the instance.